# unable to fetch data from link table using WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a aspnet_Users table with UserD as primary key and master_actor table with ActorID as primary key and have no common key..

The two tables are linked together using a link table master_actorlink table with UserID and ActorID columns..

I want to fetch the ActorID of master_actorlink table using the UserID via WCF services..

I'm new to WCF so plz help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you trying to retrieve the id via WCF Data Services?  Or do you want to retrieve the ID via  a standard WCF service call?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have security enabled, you can pull the username from the Identity context.

```
   OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

[More information on Identity & WCF Security Context](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/identity-securitycallcontext-in-wcf/)